# "field `0` of struct is private" error on pub struct attribute

Tags: syntax, module, rust, tuples, access-modifiers

"field `0` of struct is private" error on pub struct attribute

#### In crate

```rust
pub struct A(String, String);

pub struct C {
    pub b: Vec<A>,
}
```

#### in main()

```rust
...iter().map(|my_tuple:&A| (my_tuple.0.parse::<f64>().unwrap()));
```

Why do I get an "struct is private" error when the attribute is pub, the struct is pub and the parent struct is pub?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make the pieces of the tuple type `A` `pub`. Something like this:

```
pub struct A(pub String, pub String)
```

Comment: Does this mean the information in the struct is inaccessible outside the crate? Looks like a bug in the crate. There is no impl for the struct.

Comment: If you don't add `pub` to the fields of the tuple, then they will be inaccessible outside the crate (and/or the module). An `impl` is only needed if you actually want to add fuctions to a struct. By the sound of it you're not the author of the crate (which is not clear from your question), the crate author may have intended `A` to be opaque to the outside world to prevent users relying on its internal representation. For example it might be a "handle" type. In which case there would be functions using / returning `A`. Without more code that's all speculation though.

Comment: @Ben The mere fact that there is no `impl` for the struct does not imply that you can't access the fields. They could be made accessible by conversion traits, indexing traits, any custom trait or even unrelated data structurs in the respective library.

Comment: @Ben what crate and type is it?